# In Excel how to update a cells value based on another cells background color

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I have an awkward for excel issue which i think requires some VBA. I have quite a good understanding of VBA however this has got me stumped.

I have conditional formatting which checks the % given in column A, based on this value it fills cells a certain color, for example the user can input 50% which would fill half of the cells see below,

[image]

Now my boss wants it to go the other way round so if he filled a cell a color himself it would aromatically populate the % column with 50% for example

Thanks in advance

Benjiii

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried so far and the code you are using now?

Comment: and by next week, its not 100% needed but i kinda said it wont be too bad.... thinking surely excel has a formula for this... but yeah here we are haha

Comment: And what i have tried so far issss basically this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008632/excel-can-i-create-a-conditional-formula-based-on-the-color-of-a-cell

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trick to accomplish this. Since Excel VBA does not provide an event to capture range color change events, you need something else to trigger your code. You can accomplish this by tying the color cells to list validation and allowing only "" (null) and "OK" values. No text will be visible because we will make the text same color as the background but you can then capture change events. User can select "" or "OK" from the lists. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rowStart As Integer
Dim rowEnd As Integer
Dim colStart As Integer
Dim colEnd As Integer
  rowStart = 3  'insert correct values according to your sheet
  rowEnd = 10
  colStart = 2
  colEnd = 7
  With Target
    If .Count = 1 Then
      .Font.Color = .Interior.Color
      If .Row >= rowStart And .Row <= rowEnd And .Column >= colStart And .Column <= colEnd Then
        If Target = " " Then
          Cells(.Row, colStart - 1) = (.Column - colStart + 1) / (colEnd - colStart + 1)
        Else
          Worksheet_Change Target.Offset(, -1)
        End If
      End If
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```